# JAVA multithreaded server sockets

Tags: java, websocket, serversocket, java-threads

Following is the code (**JAVA**) that accepts a client socket connection and assigns a thread to each connection.

```
 ServerSocket m_ServerSocket = new ServerSocket();

 while (true) {
            java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            System.out.println(today+" - Listening to new connections...");

           Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();
           ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread( clientSocket);
           cliThread.start();
 }
```

Suppose 5 clients are connected, hence 5 threads are running.

```
client 1: threadId 11
client 2: threadId 12
client 3 :threadId 13
client 4 :threadId 14
client 5 :threadId 15
```

**Suppose one of the clients sends a message "kill-client1" , I to wish end client 1's connection and kill the thread with Id 11, something like this :**

```
public void run() {
  try {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

   while (running) {
    String clientCommand = in .readLine();

    if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Kill-client1")) {
       // end the connection for client 1 & kill it's corresponding thread 11
    }
   }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
```

**How can I achieve this ?**

Comment: so you basicly wants for clients to be able to kill other clients:)

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep track of all client sockets and/or handling threads.

```
Map<Integer,Socket> clients=new HashMap<>();

 while (true) {
            java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            System.out.println(today+" - Listening to new connections...");

           Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();
           clients.put(generateNewClientId(),clientSocket);
           ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread( clientSocket);
           cliThread.start();
 }
```

And then if you simply do

```
{
    if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Kill")) {
       Socket socket=clients.get(idToShutDown);// get required id somehow (from request??)
       socket.close();
    }
}
```

This will close given socket resulting in breaking `in.readLine()` in handling thread thus finishing thread.

If you keep track of threads, you can set "interrupt" flag and probe it in `while` condition so your handling thread will be able to finish work gracefully.

Comment: Seems this gets me closer , let me try Thanks ! If this works I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I've decided to use a combination of you answer's logic & @Nicolas Filottoanswer . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by storing your `Threads` into a **thread-safe map** (as it will be accessed by several threads concurrently) using the thread id as key

```
// Map that will contain all my threads
Map<Long, ClientServiceThread> threads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// Add to the constructor the instance of the class that manage the threads
ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(this, clientSocket);
// Add my new thread 
threads.put(cliThread.getId(), cliThread);
cliThread.start();
```

Then when a kill is launched

```
String clientCommand = in.readLine().toLowerCase();
if (clientCommand.startsWith("kill")) {
    main.interrupt(Long.valueOf(clientCommand.substring(4).trim()));
}
```

Then in the main class your method would look like:

```
public void interrupt(long threadId) {
    // Remove the thread from the map
    ClientServiceThread cliThread = threads.remove(threadId);
    if (cliThread != null) {
        // Interrupt the thread
        cliThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Finally you will need to make your class `ClientServiceThread` sensitive to interruptions

```
try {
    ...
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // My code here
    }
} finally {
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: I've decided to use a combination of you answer's logic & @Antoniossss answer . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To stop the current thread, you [close the socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()), and return from the run() method:

```
if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Kill")) {
   clientSocket.close();
   return;
}
```

EDIT:

To close another thread, you can, for example

- share a thread-safe map of clientID-Thread entries between threads. When a new client connects, you store the Thread started for this client in this map
- when a Kill-client1 command comes in, you get the Thread corresponging the "client1" key from the map, and call ìnterrupt() on this thread.
- in each thread (for example, the client1 thread), at each iteration of the loop, you check what the value of Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(). If it's true, then you close the connection, remove the thread from the shared map, and return from the `run()` method.

The key point is that you never kill another thread. You always request a thread to stop by interrupting it, and the thread checks the value of its interrupt flag to decide when and how it must stop.

Comment: I dont want the thread to kill itself, rather I want other threads or maybe the parent process to kill it based on thread ID

Comment: You should clarify your question then, because that's not clear. How would the thread know which other thread to kill based on just the command "Kill"?

Comment: Yes you are right let me edit my question but please help

Answer (score 0):

Just terminate the loop:

```
   while (running) {
    String clientCommand = in .readLine();

    if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Kill")) {
       running = false;
    }
   }
```

or:

```
   while (running) {
    String clientCommand = in .readLine();

    if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Kill")) {
       break;
    }
   }
```

And don't forget to close the socket in `finally` block.

Comment: I dont want the thread to kill itself, rather I want other threads or maybe the parent process to kill it based on thread ID